# How to integrate python script in a django project

Tags: python, django, mongodb

So I am extremely new to programming, and am stuck at this issue, I am using python with Django and Mongodb for database. I need to write a service that assigns an ID (not the one assigned by mongodb) upon each user form submission. for example entry 1's ID will be [Prefix entered by user] 2101, entry 2's ID will be [Prefix entered by user] 2102, so its basically adding in the number 2100.
I have no idea how and where to integrate this logic in my code. I have tried a few solutions on the internet but nothing seems to work.

my code:

Model.py

class Writeups(Document):

```
blog_id = 2100
title = fields.StringField(max_length=120)
date_created = fields.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
date_modified = fields.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
version_number = fields.DecimalField(null= True , max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
storage_path = fields.StringField(max_length=120)
STRIKE_READY_BRIEF = 'SRB'
STRIKE_READY_THREAT_REPORT = 'SRTR'
PREFIX_CHOICES = [
    (STRIKE_READY_BRIEF, 'SRB'),
    (STRIKE_READY_THREAT_REPORT, 'SRTR'),
]
prefix = fields.StringField(
    max_length=4,
    choices=PREFIX_CHOICES,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
    )
```

views.py:

@csrf_exempt
def writeups_request(request):

```
"""
Writeup Request
"""
if request.method == 'GET':
    try:
        data = {
            'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',
            'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
        }
        writeups = WriteupsFormset(data)
        # print(writeup)
        return render(request, "writeups/writeups.html", {'writeups_forms': writeups})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        response = {"error": "Error occurred"}
        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
if request.method == 'POST':
    writeup_data = WriteupsFormset(request.POST)
    if writeup_data.is_valid():
        flag = False
        logs = []
        for writeups_data in writeup_data:
            print(writeups_data)
            if writeups_data.cleaned_data.get('DELETE'):  # and malware_data._should_delete_form(form):
                continue
            title = writeups_data.cleaned_data.get('title')
            date_created = writeups_data.cleaned_data.get('date_created')
            date_modified = writeups_data.cleaned_data.get('date_modified')
            version_number = writeups_data.cleaned_data.get('version_number')
            storage_path = writeups_data.cleaned_data.get('storage_path')
            prefix = writeups_data.cleaned_data.get('prefix')
            try:
                writeups = Writeups(),
                                  title=title,
                                  date_created=date_created,
                                  date_modified=date_modified,
                                  version_number=version_number,
                                  storage_path=storage_path,
                                  prefix=prefix)

                writeups.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement your custom script at all submissions, Django's `Signals` are the solution for your use case. Look into `post_save` and `pre-save` signals and use them as per your problem.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/

If you have an existing database and you want a script to iterate through it and update the dataset, you can take a look at `Management Commands`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/